# How to apply a thickness for this door?

Tags: html, css

Please see the code in the code pen in [this link](http://codepen.io/Suwini/pen/NxqvzG).
I wasted two or three hours on this and decided to not to waste anymore.
I already tried the code [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/y7rQL) and it is not working.

```
.coin {
    background-image: url("http://coins.thefuntimesguide.com/images/blogs/presidential-dollar-coin-reverse-statue-of-liberty-public-domain.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: .5s linear;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.coin:after {
    background-color: #a37131;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.25), hsla(0,0%,0%,.25));
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    left: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 5px;
    z-index: -10;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
.coin:before {
    background-color: #a37131;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.25), hsla(0,0%,0%,.25));
    border-radius: 100%;
    content: '';
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-5px);
}
.coin:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
```

All I want to know is how to apply thickness to the door visible to a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;` to 'div.thumb' element.